# MySQL : UPDATE query and allows negative

Tags: mysql, sql-update

The objective of this code is to deduct `ringgit` value and `sen` value in respective column and allows the value to be negative.

Assuming the price of item to purchase are RM1.50, and the users' balance are RM 0.80, RM 2.40 and RM -1.00.

The table should look like this :

Before purchase was made

| Id | user | ringgit | sen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User A | 0 | 80 |
| 2 | User B | 2 | 40 |
| 3 | User C | -1 | 0 |

After purchase was made.

| Id | user | ringgit | sen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User A | 0 | -70 |
| 2 | User B | 0 | 90 |
| 3 | User C | -2 | -50 |

---

I used code below to deduct user's balance. But the code only can deduct correctly if the user's balance is sufficient to purchase the item. (no negative value allowed)

```
UPDATE users SET ringgit = CASE 
WHEN (sen - ".$senToDeduct." < 0) THEN (ringgit - ".$ringgitToDeduct." - 1) 
WHEN (sen - ".$senToDeduct." >= 0) THEN (ringgit - ".$ringgitToDeduct.") 
END, 
sen = 
CASE 
WHEN (sen - ".$senToDeduct." < 0) THEN (100 - (".$senToDeduct." - sen)) 
WHEN (sen - ".$senToDeduct." >= 0) THEN (sen - ".$senToDeduct.") END WHERE Id = 1
```

I try to use code as follows :

```
UPDATE users SET ringgit = 
CASE

WHEN (((ringgit * 100) + sen) - 150 >= 0) THEN LEFT(((ringgit * 100) + sen) - 150,char_length(((ringgit * 100) + sen) - 150)-2)
WHEN (((ringgit * 100) + sen) - 150 < 0) THEN - LEFT(((abs(ringgit) * 100) + abs(sen) - 150),char_length(((abs(ringgit) * 100) + abs(sen) - 250))-2) 
END, 
sen = CASE 

WHEN (((ringgit * 100) + sen) - 150 >= 0) THEN RIGHT(((ringgit * 100) + sen) - 150,2)
WHEN (((ringgit * 100) + sen) - 150 < 0) THEN - RIGHT(((abs(ringgit) * 100) + abs(sen) - 150),2)
END
WHERE Id = 1
```

..but it does not work as the ringgit column already got affected after the query run `SET ringgit =`

Comment: What don't you store value by `numeric` type?

Comment: the ringgit and sen column data type are integer, and unfortunately I can't simply change the schema.